# Get response from remotely executed .exe

Tags: c#, .net, cmd, remote-server, psexec

I am executing a .exe that sits on a remote server however PsExec seems to hang and the local service does not exit. The .exe does run successfully on the server however when it is finished I want the local service to exit.

This is the code I have atm:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\PSTools\PsExec.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"\\<remote .exe path>";
p.Start();

//I have tried the following to exit the local service when a response is
//received but it still hangs.
//string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
//string errormessage = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
//p.WaitForExit();
```

What do I need to do to exit the local service when the remote service has finished?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try  `p.WaitForInputIdle();` ?

------------- UPDATE

Difference GUI/non-GUI: [How can I tell if a process has a graphical interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785698/how-can-i-tell-if-a-process-has-a-graphical-interface)

Comment: I hadn't, but I just did and I got the error "WaitForInputIdle failed.  This could be because the process does not have a graphical interface." The remote .exe just kicks off a console to run some operations. Thank you for the suggestion :)

Comment: Certainly curious error (never seen before). But see what I found when I type it in google http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785698/how-can-i-tell-if-a-process-has-a-graphical-interface it seems like a solution for your problem: one of the answers gives options to track if the process has exited for both cases with and without GUI.

Answer (score 0):

You could try running psexec with the -d option, which is recommended for non-interactive applications. Or you could maybe set a timeout option on psexec?

Comment: I can't use the -d option as I need to only continue once the remote service has finished not just after it has started. I would use a timeout but the operation completed by the remote service can take between a couple of minutes up to an overnight period so it's not really a viable option.

Comment: If you run psexec from command line, does it execute successfully? If so, maybe create a batch file to execute psexec and have your code start a process for the batch file.

Comment: Reasoning is that maybe psexec isn't redirecting output to your applicaation correctly